# Error in seq.default(from = min(k), to = max(k), length = nBreaks + 1) : 'from' must be a finite number. WISH-R package

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of pre-filtered genomic regions (based on previous GWAS and some enrichment analysis performed on GSEA) and I am looking for interesting gene-gene interactions.
i have a binary phenotype and i have used glm=T in the model of course.
I have followed in detail the WISH-R guide - https://github.com/QSG-Group/WISH -  and generated the correlations matrix without issues.
I am now struggling to use the generate.modules function, so I am writing here for some help.
i have tried several times to run generate.modules(correlations,values="Coefficients",thread=2)
before that I have also run as suggested:

```
correlations$Coefficients[(is.na(correlations$Coefficients))]<-0
correlations$Pvalues[(is.na(correlations$Pvalues))]<-1
```

This is my R code:

```
library(WISH)
library(data.table)
ped <- fread("D:/Dati/GWAS_ITALIAN_PBC_Mike_files/EPISTASI/epistasi_all SNPs_all_TF/file_epistasi_per_wish/all_snp_tf_recoded.ped", data.table=F)
tped <- fread("D:/Dati/GWAS_ITALIAN_PBC_Mike_files/EPISTASI/epistasi_all SNPs_all_TF/file_epistasi_per_wish/all_snp_tf_recoded.tped", data.table=F)
pval <- fread("D:/Dati/GWAS_ITALIAN_PBC_Mike_files/EPISTASI/epistasi_all SNPs_all_TF/file_epistasi_per_wish/ALL_SNP_TF_p.txt", data.table=F)
id <- fread("D:/Dati/GWAS_ITALIAN_PBC_Mike_files/EPISTASI/epistasi_all SNPs_all_TF/file_epistasi_per_wish/ALL_SNP_TF_id.txt", data.table=F)
genotype <-generate.genotype(ped,tped,snp.id=id, pvalue=0.005,id.select=NULL,gwas.p=pval,major.freq=0.95,fast.read=T)
LD_genotype<-LD_blocks(genotype)
genotype <- LD_genotype$genotype
pheno<-fread("D:/Dati/GWAS_ITALIAN_PBC_Mike_files/EPISTASI/epistasi_all SNPs_all_TF/file_epistasi_per_wish/pheno.txt",data.table=F)
pheno<-ifelse(pheno=="1","0","1")
pheno<-as.numeric(pheno)
correlations<-epistatic.correlation(pheno, genotype,threads = 2 ,test=F,glm=T)
genome.interaction(tped,correlations,quantile = 0.9)
correlations$Coefficients[(is.na(correlations$Coefficients))]<-0
correlations$Pvalues[(is.na(correlations$Pvalues))]<-1
generate.modules(correlations,values="Coefficients",thread=2)
```

**I get the following error:
Error in seq.default(from = min(k), to = max(k), length = nBreaks + 1) :
'from' must be a finite number.**

Do you have some hints to debug this error here?
What is the main issue here?

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Don’t add data/code as images. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Do I need to attach input files?

Comment: so my problem occurs when generate.modules function is called. it operates on correlations. correlations is a list including coefficients or pvalues. should I attach the content?